# How to check for values in a column depending on its values in the future in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Subject     First Date  ER Date     Score
phchp003                10/25/2005  0
phchp003    5/5/2006        
phchp003    11/11/2016  5/5/2006    1
phchp003    3/7/2018    11/11/2016  1
phchp003                3/7/2018    1
phchp003            
phchp004    11/19/2016      
phchp004    1/12/2018   11/19/2016  1
phchp004    6/3/2019    1/12/2018   1
phchp004    6/24/2019   6/3/2019    1
phchp004    7/27/2019   6/24/2019   1
phchp005                7/27/2019   1
phchp005                7/28/2019   0
phchp005            
phchp006        
phchp006            
phchp006                12/4/2007   0
phchp006                8/5/2009    0
phchp006                11/28/2009  0
phchp006    9/2/2017    1/4/2017    0
phchp006    11/19/2017  9/2/2017    1
```

I am essentially looking in the score column for a score of 1, finding the ER Date, and then putting it into the first date column exactly one row above where it occurs.  I then fill the first date column from the bottom up, to get this:

```
Subject     First Date  ER Date     Score
phchp003    5/5/2006    10/25/2005  0
phchp003    5/5/2006        
phchp003    11/11/2016  5/5/2006    1
phchp003    3/7/2018    11/11/2016  1
phchp003    11/19/2016  3/7/2018    1
phchp003    11/19/2016      
phchp004    11/19/2016      
phchp004    1/12/2018   11/19/2016  1
phchp004    6/3/2019    1/12/2018   1
phchp004    6/24/2019   6/3/2019    1
phchp004    7/27/2019   6/24/2019   1
phchp005    9/2/2017    7/27/2019   1
phchp005    9/2/2017    7/28/2019   0
phchp005    9/2/2017        
phchp006    9/2/2017    
phchp006    9/2/2017        
phchp006    9/2/2017    12/4/2007   0
phchp006    9/2/2017    8/5/2009    0
phchp006    9/2/2017    11/28/2009  0
phchp006    9/2/2017    1/4/2017    0
phchp006    11/19/2017  9/2/2017    1
```

However, my above solution does not take into account the subject ID so it copies the First Date into different subjects when it should only recognize that subjects ER date and score.  If there are no more ER dates with a score of 1 for that subject, then those first dates should get a date of 12/31/1899, as shown below:
I need this:

```
Subject First Date  ER Date Score
phchp003    5/5/2006    10/25/2005  0
phchp003    5/5/2006        
phchp003    11/11/2016  5/5/2006    1
phchp003    3/7/2018    11/11/2016  1
phchp003    12/30/1899  3/7/2018    1
phchp003    12/30/1899      
phchp004    11/19/2016      
phchp004    1/12/2018   11/19/2016  1
phchp004    6/3/2019    1/12/2018   1
phchp004    6/24/2019   6/3/2019    1
phchp004    12/30/1899  6/24/2019   1
phchp005    12/30/1899  7/27/2019   1
phchp005    12/30/1899  7/28/2019   0
phchp005    12/30/1899      
phchp006    9/2/2017        
phchp006    9/2/2017        
phchp006    9/2/2017    12/4/2007   0
phchp006    9/2/2017    8/5/2009    0
phchp006    9/2/2017    11/28/2009  0
phchp006    9/2/2017    1/4/2017    0
phchp006    12/30/1899  9/2/2017    1
```

How should I go about doing this? I have a large set of data in this format, thanks.

Comment: why you are getting `12/30/1899` instead of `7/27/2019` at index position 10 in your expected output?

Comment: @AnuragDabas this is because that date is a different subject, 004 vs 005, therefor it doesn't carry over the date you mentioned and instead takes 12/30/1899.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
df['First Date'] = (df.groupby('Subject')
                      .apply(lambda x: x['ER Date'].where(x['Score'] == 1).shift(-1).bfill())
                      .fillna('12/30/1899').reset_index(level=0, drop=True))

df
```

Output:

```
     Subject  First Date     ER Date  Score
0   phchp003    5/5/2006  10/25/2005    0.0
1   phchp003    5/5/2006         NaN    NaN
2   phchp003  11/11/2016    5/5/2006    1.0
3   phchp003    3/7/2018  11/11/2016    1.0
4   phchp003  12/30/1899    3/7/2018    1.0
5   phchp003  12/30/1899         NaN    NaN
6   phchp004  11/19/2016         NaN    NaN
7   phchp004   1/12/2018  11/19/2016    1.0
8   phchp004    6/3/2019   1/12/2018    1.0
9   phchp004   6/24/2019    6/3/2019    1.0
10  phchp004  12/30/1899   6/24/2019    1.0
11  phchp005  12/30/1899   7/27/2019    1.0
12  phchp005  12/30/1899   7/28/2019    0.0
13  phchp005  12/30/1899         NaN    NaN
14  phchp006    9/2/2017         NaN    NaN
15  phchp006    9/2/2017         NaN    NaN
16  phchp006    9/2/2017   12/4/2007    0.0
17  phchp006    9/2/2017    8/5/2009    0.0
18  phchp006    9/2/2017  11/28/2009    0.0
19  phchp006    9/2/2017    1/4/2017    0.0
20  phchp006  12/30/1899    9/2/2017    1.0
```